# mysql select distinct letters, including extended latin characters

Tags: mysql, sql

Original question:

> Table structure:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `texts` (
>   `letter` VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
>   `text` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
>   INDEX (`letter` ASC),
>   INDEX (`text` ASC)
> )
> ENGINE InnoDB
> CHARACTER SET utf8
> COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
> ```
>
> Sample data:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO `texts`
> (`letter`, `text`)
> VALUES
> ('a', 'Apple'),
> ('ā', 'Ābols'),
> ('b', 'Bull'),
> ('c', 'Cell'),
> ('č', 'Čakste');
> ```
>
> The query which I'm executing:
>
> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT `letter` FROM `texts`;
> ```
>
> Expected results:
>
> ```
> `letter`
> a
> ā
> b
> c
> č
> ```
>
> Actual results:
>
> ```
> `letter`
> a
> b
> c
> ```
>
> I've tried many utf8 collations (utf8_[bin|general_ci|unicode_ci],
>   utf8mb4_[bin|general_ci|unicode_ci] etc), none of them work. How to
>   fix this?
>
> Edit for clarification: what I want is not just to get all the letters
>   out, but also get them in the order I specified in the expected
>   results. `utf8_bin` gets all the letters, but they are ordered in the
>   wrong way - extended latin characters follow only after all the basic
>   latin characters (example: a, b, c, ā, č). Also, the actual table I'm
>   using has many texts per letter, so grouping is a must.

Edit #2: here's the full table data from the live site - http://pastebin.com/cH2DUzf3
Executing that SQL and running the following query after that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BINARY `letter` FROM `texts` ORDER BY `letter` ASC
```

yields *almost* perfect results, with one exception: the letter 'ū' is *before* 'u', which is weird to say the least, because all other extended latin letters show up after their basic latin versions. How do I solve this one last problem?

Comment: Did you try `utf8_bin`?

Comment: @juergend - added an edit to clarify one thing.

Comment: Curious to know what is the result of :
SELECT `letter` FROM `texts`;

Comment: @ak0053792 - that would work for me if the all the texts were starting with a unique letter, but in the actual table, each letter has up to a hundred different texts, so I need to group them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [**Manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) for `BINARY` type

```
SELECT DISTINCT BINARY `letter` FROM `texts`
```

Check [<kbd>**SQL Fiddle**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59c8f)

Comment: That works great, thanks! phpMyAdmin displays the extended latin letters like 'c481' instead of 'ā', but when exporting the resultset, it shows up fine.

Comment: Ah, one thing though. I have the INDEX on the `letter` column and by default it orders the letters correctly, but if I add `ORDER BY letter ASC` to the query, the ordering becomes wrong, the extended latin characters go after basic latin again. Why is that? Here's an example of what I mean: http://pastebin.com/57an2pCX

Comment: Check this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f5eb5/1 there is no any problem in Order clause

Comment: Yeah there is, that fiddle outputs 'ā' before 'a' and 'ū' before 'u'.